# Criteria for default garbage collector Hotspot JVM 11/17

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, java-11, java-17

I found a [source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/available-collectors.html#GUID-F215A508-9E58-40B4-90A5-74E29BF3BD3C) describing that the default gc used changes depending on the available resources. It seems that the jvm uses either g1gc or serial gc dependnig on hardware and os.

> The serial collector is selected by default on certain hardware and operating system configurations

Can someone point out a more detailed source on what the specific criteria is and how that would apply in a dockerized/kubernetes enivronment.
In other words:

Could setting resource requests of the pod in k8s to eg. 1500 mCpu make the jvm use serial gc and changing to 2 Cpu change the default gc to g1gc? Do the limits on when which gc is used change depending on jvm version (11 vs 17)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In current OpenJDK, G1 GC is chosen by default for the "server class machine", or Serial GC otherwise. "Server class machine" is defined as a system with 2 or more non-HT CPUs and 2 or more GiB RAM.

The exact algorithm can be found in [src/hotspot/share/runtime/os.cpp](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/3121898c33fa3cc5a049977f8677105a84c3e50c/src/hotspot/share/runtime/os.cpp#L1673):

```
// This is the working definition of a server class machine:
// >= 2 physical CPU's and >=2GB of memory, with some fuzz
// because the graphics memory (?) sometimes masks physical memory.
// If you want to change the definition of a server class machine
// on some OS or platform, e.g., >=4GB on Windows platforms,
// then you'll have to parameterize this method based on that state,
// as was done for logical processors here, or replicate and
// specialize this method for each platform.  (Or fix os to have
// some inheritance structure and use subclassing.  Sigh.)
// If you want some platform to always or never behave as a server
// class machine, change the setting of AlwaysActAsServerClassMachine
// and NeverActAsServerClassMachine in globals*.hpp.
bool os::is_server_class_machine() {
  // First check for the early returns
  if (NeverActAsServerClassMachine) {
    return false;
  }
  if (AlwaysActAsServerClassMachine) {
    return true;
  }
  // Then actually look at the machine
  bool         result            = false;
  const unsigned int    server_processors = 2;
  const julong server_memory     = 2UL * G;
  // We seem not to get our full complement of memory.
  //     We allow some part (1/8?) of the memory to be "missing",
  //     based on the sizes of DIMMs, and maybe graphics cards.
  const julong missing_memory   = 256UL * M;

  /* Is this a server class machine? */
  if ((os::active_processor_count() >= (int)server_processors) &&
      (os::physical_memory() >= (server_memory - missing_memory))) {
    const unsigned int logical_processors =
      VM_Version::logical_processors_per_package();
    if (logical_processors > 1) {
      const unsigned int physical_packages =
        os::active_processor_count() / logical_processors;
      if (physical_packages >= server_processors) {
        result = true;
      }
    } else {
      result = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! 
Btw.: Gotta love these "?"  everywhere like, these guys should know

> We allow some part (1/8?) of the memory to be "missing"
>  [...] with some fuzz because the graphics memory (?) sometimes masks physical memory [...]

Comment: @Paul7979 it’s not as if one person had written everything. Most probably, someone tried to recap was this already existing code is doing, at some later time. I wish, someone would do the same with the code that is responsible for the array length limitation (the fact that we can’t allocate `new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE]`), as apparently no-one really knows why this limitation exists.

Comment: Am aware of that, but it seems like there is some black magic even for the maintainers of the jdk going on. (as your example is pointing out)

Answer (score 32):

In JDK 11 and 17 `Serial` collector is used when there is only one CPU available. Otherwise `G1` is selected

If you limit the number of CPUS available to your container, JVM selects `Serial` instead of the default`G1`

### JDK11

##### 1 CPU

```
docker run --cpus=1 --rm -it eclipse-temurin:11 java -Xlog:gc* -version
[0.004s][info][gc] Using **Serial**
```

It uses `Serial`

##### More than one CPU

```
docker run --cpus=2 --rm -it eclipse-temurin:11 java -Xlog:gc* -version
[0.008s][info][gc     ] Using G1
```

It uses `G1`

### JDK17

##### 1 CPU

```
docker run --cpus=1 --rm -it eclipse-temurin:17 java -Xlog:gc* -version
[0.004s][info][gc] Using Serial
```

It uses `Serial`

##### More than one CPU

```
docker run --cpus=2 --rm -it eclipse-temurin:17 java -Xlog:gc* -version
[0.007s][info][gc] Using G1
```

It uses `G1`

Comment: Since Java 19 the JVM does not longer, by default, take cpu.shares into account. You must use -XX:+UseContainerCpuShares to restore the old behavior. This was also backported to Java 11 and 17, causing some applications to experience OOM. 
See here fro some discussions: https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/hotspot-runtime-dev/2022-December/059239.html